# Chat Application in java without polling concept

Tags: java, chat, jruby

I have created one to one a chat application in java using spring3. What it does is polling the database for new messages for the particular user. This is still a development code and can't give it to production & u know what will happen.

I want to create a chat application without this polling concept. I need the users to get messages when the messages arrive for them only more like push. I searched and found results for web sockets, comet,XMPP etc and most of them need specific server and beta versions. I am running my application in IBM WebSphere.

Anybody have any idea what to do? Does J Ruby a worthy try?

Comment: When you want to circumvent the HTTP protocol, you should switch to a Java rich client which works with sockets.

Comment: I dont know of which type your client is but you could try JMS. Unless your client is a website the user still has to refresh the page or you  have to implement some polling I guess.

Comment: You could look at Meteor, which would handle pushing the messages automatically for you

Comment: @jumpingcode does it require any seperate server like comet?

Comment: @Smutje sockets only applies for html5. We can't push it into production hoping all users uses html5 right. Thats where I faced the problem. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: @ArunRaj Not as far as I'm aware

Answer (score 1):

JMS topics would provide you publish/subscribe and (still) server side persistence in one shot.

A client subscribes to a topic in a JMS queue, and then "waits" for new messages. You may even support clients that are disconnected and they would still receive missed messages on reconnect. Messages from a client can be written into another queue, consumed by your MDB in the server and redistributed to the outgoing queue.

Your WebSphere should provide you with JMS queues as far as i remember, and the client code for receiving messages is probably less than 10 lines of code ;-)

Oracle client examples: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/jms/tutorial/1_3_1-fcs/doc/client_samples.html

Comment: I tried with web sockets and node js and comet. It worked but the only problem is that web sockets require html5.